# android passing value from javascript to android

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on android application with google map api 3 using webview. My android application lets a user to tap a marked location on the map and then sends the user to an activity on android (from webview to another activity). My problem is I don't know where to start. I think its how to pass javascript value to java(android). Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Check the following android documentation.
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html